# How to use nvd3 indentedTree with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 charts in my code and I have used it for pie charts, but I don't know how to use it for indentedTree. Can anyone give me an example. Here is the code I used for pie chart.

**HTML**

```
<nvd3-pie-chart data="exampleData1"
      class="pie"
      id="labelTypePercentExample"
      x="xFunction()"
      y="yFunction()"
      showLabels="true"
      pieLabelsOutside="true"
      showLegend="true"
      rightAlign="true"
      labelType="percent">
  </nvd3-pie-chart>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.exampleData1 = [
  { key: "Ongoing", y: 20 },
    { key: "completed", y: 10 }
];
```

Can anyone give me a similar example for indentedTree

Comment: I guess you are using [angularjs-nvd3-directives](http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives) library, unfortunately, it doesn't seems to support the indentedTree. One option is to use the nvd3 directly yourself.

Comment: Thank. I have found a directive to use instead, Angular.treeview [https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since angularjs-nvd3-directives doesn't support indentedTree, there is a directive [Angular.treeview](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview),It will do the same